# mongoose, omitting/removing a property from each element of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a document like this

```
{
  _id: ...
  deletedAt: null
  history: [
   {
     _id: ...
     name: ...
     deletedAt: null
   },
   {
     _id: ...
     name: ...
     deletedAt: null
   },
  ]
}
```

after saving a document i want to return the saved document without properties
`deletedAt` and `history.$.deletedAt`

i have post middleware

```
mySchema.post('save', function () {
  this.set('history.$[].deletedAt', undefined);
  this.set('history.$.deletedAt', undefined);
  this.set('deletedAt', undefined);
});
```

this middleware removes the `deletedAt` but it's not removing `history.$.deletedAt`
when i do `history.0.deletedAt` this works , but only for the first item of the array. how to make this work for all elements of the array?

also in my model i have specified `select: false` like this

```
...
history: {
  type: [{
    ...
    deletedAt: { type: Date, default: null, select: false }
    ...
  }],
}
...
```

but any case history[n].deletedAt is being selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this way

```
mySchema.post('save', function () {
  this.history.forEach((v, i) => this.set(`history.${i}.deletedAt`, undefined));
  this.set('deletedAt', undefined);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()`

```
// Remove the deletedAt key from each object in the history array
const historyWithoutDeletedAt = savedDoc.history.map(({ deletedAt, ...rest }) => rest);

// Create a new object without the deletedAt key and with the updated history array
const result = { ...savedDoc.toObject(), deletedAt: undefined, history: historyWithoutDeletedAt };

// Return the new object
return result;
```